# Unable to play ACC stream using AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer

Tags: swift, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I am working on an app that receives a stream of packets with video and audio. I was able to decode the video and play it using `AVSampleBufferDisplayLayer`. (Code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/MrdotSpock/64ba5a1cca0fac29a537b9598c55810b)) But I've been struggling for over a week to decode the audio. At the beginning of the stream, I receive an audio description like this -> `sampleRate=48000`, `channelCount=1`, and `profileLevel=2`.Then I continuously receive packets of ACC data which I try to decode in a similar way as I treat the video packets. In the beginning, I create `AudioStreamBasicDescription`, `CMAudioFormatDescription`, and setup the `audioRenderer` and `audioRendererSynchoronizer`.

```
   class AudioDecoderPlayer: NSObject {
  private var audioRenderer = AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer()
  private var audioRendererSynchoronizer = AVSampleBufferRenderSynchronizer()
  private let serializationQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "sample.buffer.player.serialization.queue")

  private var audioStreamBasicDescription: AudioStreamBasicDescription
  private var formatDescription: CMAudioFormatDescription?

  private var outputQueue: AudioQueueRef?

  var sampleBuffers: [CMSampleBuffer] = []
  
  let sampleRate: Double
  let channels: Int

  init(sampleRate: Double = 48000, channels: Int = 1, profileLevel: Int = 2) {

    self.sampleRate = sampleRate
    self.channels = channels
    
    let uChannels = UInt32(channels)
    let channelBytes = UInt32(MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
    let bytesPerFrame = uChannels * channelBytes


    self.audioStreamBasicDescription = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
      mSampleRate: Float64(sampleRate),
      mFormatID: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
      mFormatFlags: AudioFormatFlags(profileLevel),
      mBytesPerPacket: bytesPerFrame,
      mFramesPerPacket: 1,
      mBytesPerFrame: bytesPerFrame,
      mChannelsPerFrame: uChannels,
      mBitsPerChannel: channelBytes * 8,
      mReserved: 0
    )

    super.init()
    
    let status = CMAudioFormatDescriptionCreate(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault, asbd: &audioStreamBasicDescription, layoutSize: 0, layout: nil, magicCookieSize: 0, magicCookie: nil, extensions: nil, formatDescriptionOut: &formatDescription)

    if status != noErr {
      fatalError("unable to create audio format description")
    }
    
    
    audioRendererSynchoronizer.addRenderer(audioRenderer)
    subscribeToAudioRenderer()
    startPlayback()
  }
  
  func subscribeToAudioRenderer() {
    audioRenderer.requestMediaDataWhenReady(on: serializationQueue, using: { [weak self] in
      guard let strongSelf = self else {
        return
      }
      
      while strongSelf.audioRenderer.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
        if let sampleBuffer = strongSelf.nextSampleBuffer() {
          strongSelf.audioRenderer.enqueue(sampleBuffer)
        }
      }
    })
  }
  
  func startPlayback() {
    serializationQueue.async {
      if self.audioRendererSynchoronizer.rate != 1 {
        self.audioRendererSynchoronizer.rate = 1
        self.audioRenderer.volume = 1.0
      }
    }
  }
  
  func nextSampleBuffer() -> CMSampleBuffer? {
    guard sampleBuffers.count > 0 else {
      return nil
    }
    
    let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffers.first
    sampleBuffers.remove(at: 0)
    
    return sampleBuffer
  }
```

And this is how my decode function looks like

```
  func decodeAudioPacket(data: Data) {
    let headerValue = UInt32(data.count)

    //add data lenght at the beginning
    var sizedData = withUnsafeBytes(of: headerValue.bigEndian) { Data($0) }
    sizedData.append(data)

    let blockBuffer = sizedData.toCMBlockBuffer()

    // Outputs from CMSampleBufferCreate
    var sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?

    let result = CMAudioSampleBufferCreateReadyWithPacketDescriptions(
      allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
      dataBuffer: blockBuffer,
      formatDescription: formatDescription!,
      sampleCount: 1,
      presentationTimeStamp: CMTime(value: 1, timescale: Int32(sampleRate)),
      packetDescriptions: nil,
      sampleBufferOut: &sampleBuffer)


    if result != noErr {
      fatalError("CMSampleBufferCreate() failed")
    }

    sampleBuffers.append(sampleBuffer!)
  }
```

I found out that `requestMediaDataWhenReady` is only called once which suggests, that the sound is not being played, but I don't understand why. I was able to make it work by editing code from WWDC 2017 session 509 but there is still no sound being played. (Code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/MrdotSpock/b085a66fbe7a38e4516a2404f2c686c2)) I've also tried to use various solutions with `AudioQueue` but with no success. (For some reasons the callbacks from `AudioFileStreamOpen` were never called) (Code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/MrdotSpock/35439e2236eccd9b8761166b29dd2c75) and [here](https://gist.github.com/MrdotSpock/4fa9344ebd05c55df37c20de642d1d5c)). But I would prefer to solve it using `AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer` as I believe it should be easier and I also want to use `AVSampleBufferAudioRendererSynchronizer` to synchronize the video with the audio.

Any suggestions on what I do wrong is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The basic stream description looks wrong and you don’t seem to be providing packet descriptions. Do you have a runnable code snippet?

Comment: I was unable to play the audio using AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer. I had to use AudioQueue which required more work but gets the job done.

Comment: Hello @Ender, I am also trying the same thing as you were (Playing the audio packets from socket). But I am using AVAudioEngine and I am having a glitch between the audio packets. Why did you prefer AudioQueue over AVAudioEngine? I dont see proper example for using AudioQueue. Can you show me the sample code of implementing the AudioQueue? 
My Result is similar to this: https://storage.googleapis.com/webfundamentals-assets/videos/gap.webm

Comment: Hi, @sudayn these glitches also occurred to me. The problem was the stream was not continuous e.g. I restarted the AudioQueue or removed a lot of packets to sync it with audio. To respond to your second question AudioQueue vs. AVAudioEngine - To be honest I do not remember why chose AudioQueue. I wanted to use the AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer and then I switched to AudioQueue.